# setting the selected item on a dropdown php msql

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I am creating a page where I would like to display captured information from the database.  One of the items I would like to display is the selected value from the dropdown list menu, but defaulting to the selected coverid

I use the following function to display the dropdown:

```
//function to display the cover in the dropdown
//function to display the cover in the dropdown
    public function coverdropdown($companyid, $coverid)
    {

        $mydata = mysql_query("SELECT a.`coverid`, a.`cover_name`, a.`sum_insured`, a.`info`
                    FROM covertype a WHERE a.`companyid`=$companyid");
            while($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata))
                {
                    echo '<option  value="'.$record['coverid'].'" if ($record['coverid']==$coverid) {selected=selected}">'.$record['cover_name'].' - R'.$record['sum_insured'].'</option>'; 
                }
    }
```

I would like the dropdown to show the selected coverid. I know its something like:

```
<option value="" selected="selected">XYZ cover</option>
```

but now i am not sure how to add that to this line, because the if statement I added is not working, its incorrect syntax:

```
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata))
            {
               echo '<option  value="'.$record['coverid'].'" if ($record['coverid']==$coverid) {selected=selected}">'.$record['cover_name'].' - R'.$record['sum_insured'].'</option>'; 
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to assign a variable before the `<option>`. Something similar to:

```
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)) {
        // One thing to note: In XHTML the selected attribute should probably be defined as <option selected="selected">.
        // In regular HTML <option selected> is ok
        $selected   =   ($record['coverid'] == $coverid)? ' selected="selected"':'';
        echo '<option  value="'.$record['coverid'].'"'.$selected.'>'.$record['cover_name'].' - R'.$record['sum_insured'].'</option>'; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

this must do the job:

```
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){
    if($record['coverid']==$coverid)
        echo '<option  value="'.$record['coverid'].' selected>'.$record['cover_name'].'</option>';
    else
        echo '<option  value="'.$record['coverid'].'>'.$record['cover_name'].'</option>';
}
```